# dynamically created table doesn't recognize unordred list tags

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

when i try to place an unorderd list fetched from the database column, into a dynamically created row of a table(using createElement) it shows the list tags along with the data. but doesn't appear formatted.

here is the code

```
var table1 = document.getElementById('pc');

for (var x = 1; x < len; x++) {
     var vals = result[x];
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
       row.textContent = vals;
       table.appendChild(row);

}
```

result is from ajax and it has the lists.

Comment: to remove list markers, use css style `list-style-type: none;`

Comment: a list cannot be a child of a tr - you need to create a td, append it to the tr and then append the list to the td

Comment: no change with list-style-type:none

Comment: vals has a list like • Animals
o Herbivorous
 Elephant
o Carnivorous
 Tiger

Comment: You're trying to create invalid HTML; as @Pete says: any element other than a `td` ***cannot*** appear as a child of a `tr` element.

Comment: instead of a tr i tried with div also. still the same. am new to javascript. and html :(

Answer (score 0):

By "it shows the list tags along with the data" do you mean it is actually showing the <li> tag instead of actually making a list item?

It might be storing it in your database as `&lt;` instead of `<`.